# Casual Agreements to Privacy and Civil Lawsuits

Tags: canada, law-in-fiction, civil-judgment, emotional-distress

So, let’s say that a husband and wife do something like this: a husband offers the wife an agreement (via a casual text message) that neither party will disclose the details of what they did in their bedroom last night (and only those two know what happened and it wasn’t anything illegal), and the wife knowingly and voluntarily agrees to the text message (e.g. by saying “yes”). Now, if the wife discloses these details to a third party and this results in the husband getting hurt emotionally and he loses friends, could the husband launch a civil lawsuit against the wife, and can he win? (Specifically under a Canadian jurisdiction. Let’s just say that this fictional scenario took place in British Columbia.)

Comment: Historically, there were legal immunities that prevented spouses from suing each other, but I assume that this is in the present, so that this simple analysis is not applicable.

Comment: Yes, it’s set in the present.